# Parent Process Directory not recognized by the Icon and Background Image fields in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, directory, path

#### Windows Terminal version

1.12.10732.0

#### Windows build number

19043.1645

#### Issue

Forgive me if this has been addressed already somewhere else, but I realized that when `Use parent process directory` is checked, `Command line` is able to run `testrun.bat`  which is located in the parent process directory but `Icon` is unable to access `test_icon.ico` which is also located in the parent process directory.

Is there a reference (such as `%USERPROFILE%` is to the home folder) to point to the parent process directory so that I can access the `test_icon.ico` file? Something along the lines of `%PARENTDIRECTORY%\test_icon.ico` or otherwise how do I deal with this?

The intent here is to have wt dynamically locate whatever `test_icon.ico` file that is present in the current parent process directory for the icon or background image settings.

[image]

#### Expected Behavior

`test_icon.ico` in the `Icon` field, Loads the .ico file as the icon. Same goes for the `background image` in the `Appearance` tab.

#### Actual Behavior

I get the following error message below...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Sep/03/Programmatically-Opening-Windows-Terminal-in-a-Specific-Folder)

In the `Icon` and `Background` fields, you can reference your files relative to your current working directory:

`%__CD__%\relative_path_to_icon_file`. In my case it would be `%__CD__%\graphics\app_bckgnd.jpg`.