# Reference unknow parts of a path in Windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables, relative-path

I'm trying to reference the midsection of a file path that may be unknown or dynamically vary, depending on the location of the folder. Using windows a combination of windows environment variables and relative paths, I tried the following to no avail:

Full path
`C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\App\graphics\app_bckgnd.jpg`

I tried `%CD%` like so `%CD%\graphics\app_bckgnd.jpg` which is supposed to point to the current parent working directory `App` but it failed.

I also tried `.\App\graphics\app_bckgnd.jpg` and that failed as well.

I resorted to using %USERPROFILE% like so  `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\App\graphics\app_bckgnd.jpg` which points to the home folder but the challenge here is the `Desktop` directory which is most likely to change depending on where the user of the app places the parent folder on their computer.

Note that the path is just a plain string that'll go in a field of a software's settings menu and is not to be used in a script or run in a shell. I was wondering if there's a way to bridge the gap regardless of what it is and still get to the target `app_bckgnd.jpg`?

###### UPDATE: Please check out my previous post for more details of the software this is pertaining to [Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890784/parent-process-directory-not-recognized-by-the-icon-and-background-image-fields)

Comment: When a program is started it has a so called *working directory*. This is normally the same folder where the executable was started from. Depending on your used tool language you can read out this directory and append a relative path to it to get to your desired destination. The question is, in what programming language is your tool written, that needs to determine the folder and combine this with a relative path?

Comment: You'll have to see whether the software's settings menu supports wildcards or "find a file with this name anywhere on my computer". Also, since you say this isn't for use in a script or running in a shell, this isn't a computer programming question, so it's off topic for this site.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks for your response. I have updated the OP with a link to another post I made with more details and answers to your questions. Pls check it out.

Comment: @RaymondChen I beg to differ. Pls check out the link as it will clear things up as well.

Comment: Okay, this question didn't mention that it's Terminal, which is a developer tool (and is therefore in scope). But for this, you'll have to ask the Terminal folks whether wildcards are allowed in that path. I suspect they aren't.